# setInterval is never firing in function and don't know why (angular)

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have this function which for some reason goes straight from printing 'submit component line after jobstart call' to 'entering while loop':

```
returned() {
    this.numReturned++;
    if (this.numReturned !== this.numSubmitting) {
        return;
    }
    console.log('submit component line before jobstart call');
    this.submitService.startJobToAuditTable().subscribe();
    console.log('submit component line after jobstart call');

    let timer = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('start of interval');
        this.submitService.checkIfJobRunning().subscribe(res => {
            console.log("res from job running check is " + res);
            this.jobFinished = res;
        });

        this.submitService.pollAuditTable().subscribe(res => {
            console.log("res from audit table:\n\t" + res);
            this.auditRows = res;
        });
    }, 10000);  //runs every 10 seconds. will be longer after testing

    console.log('entering while loop');
    while (this.jobFinished === false) {

    }

    console.log('clearing interval, job should be finished now');
    clearInterval(timer);
    return;
}
```

The console.log and other things inside of the setInterval never get called, and I am confused as to why that would be

Comment: its a async call is your service all working fine did you check

Comment: Your infinite loop is blocking everything. Don't do that.

Comment: setInterval creates an async call to the provided function, there is no pause in execution between the lines before and after it. The other console logs will show up 10 seconds latter (as per your 10000 argument). But as torazaburo mentions, you have an infinite loop, that blocks anything else from happening so those will never show up anyways

Comment: Yes, my first call to startJobToAuditTable worked fine, and every other call from the rest of the app works.

Comment: Okay so it's my infinite loop that is blocking everything. What is the correct way to do that instead of the infinite loop? I want the interval to run until this.jobFinished is changed from the call in the interval.

Comment: call the code to clear the interval after `this.jobFinished = res;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is consuming execution and blocking everything. If you want to wait until job is done instead of `while(done){}` loop you can return a promise:

```
returned() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.numReturned++;
      if (this.numReturned !== this.numSubmitting) {
          resolve();
          return;
      }
      console.log('submit component line before jobstart call');
      this.submitService.startJobToAuditTable().subscribe();
      console.log('submit component line after jobstart call');

      let timer = setInterval(() => {

          console.log('start of interval');
          this.submitService.checkIfJobRunning().subscribe(res => {
              console.log("res from job running check is " + res);
              this.jobFinished = res;
          });

          this.submitService.pollAuditTable().subscribe(res => {
              console.log("res from audit table:\n\t" + res);
              this.auditRows = res;
          });

-->       if(this.jobFinished === false) {
              console.log('clearing interval, job should be finished now');
              clearInterval(timer);
              resolve();
          }

      }, 10000);  //runs every 10 seconds. will be longer after testing

  }
}
```

`resolve()` is used instead of `return`, in asynchronous code.

Later, when you call this function, if you want to wait until jobs are finished you can use `await` keyword

```
await returned ();  // will wait until resolve() is called
// code after all jobs done
```

or if async/await is not preferred:

```
returned().then(() => {
    // code after all jobs done
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code, it's blocking, not allowing the process to trigger the next tick. So nothing else, including the setInterval will fire.

```
// Delete this
while (this.jobFinished === false) { }
```

Then you can move the clearInterval

```
this.submitService.checkIfJobRunning().subscribe(res => { 
  console.log("res from job running check is " + res); 
  this.jobFinished = res;
  if( this.jobFinished !== false ){
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you can do something like this:

```
returned() {
    this.numReturned++;
    if (this.numReturned !== this.numSubmitting) {
        return resolve();
    }
    console.log('submit component line before jobstart call');
    this.submitService.startJobToAuditTable().subscribe();
    console.log('submit component line after jobstart call');

    let timer = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('start of interval');
        this.submitService.checkIfJobRunning().subscribe(res => {
            console.log("res from job running check is " + res);
            this.jobFinished = res;

            if (this.jobFinished) {
                console.log('clearing interval, job should be finished now');
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        });

        this.submitService.pollAuditTable().subscribe(res => {
            console.log("res from audit table:\n\t" + res);
            this.auditRows = res;
        });
    }, 10000);  //runs every 10 seconds. will be longer after testing

    console.log('entering wait phase');
}
```

However, it seems you want the function to return when the job is finished, in which case you'll need to return a promise and declare its running scope as `async`:

```
returned() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.numReturned++;
        if (this.numReturned !== this.numSubmitting) {
            return resolve();
        }
        console.log('submit component line before jobstart call');
        this.submitService.startJobToAuditTable().subscribe();
        console.log('submit component line after jobstart call');

        let timer = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('start of interval');
            this.submitService.checkIfJobRunning().subscribe(res => {
                console.log("res from job running check is " + res);
                this.jobFinished = res;

                if (this.jobFinished) {
                    console.log('clearing interval, job should be finished now');
                    clearInterval(timer);

                    resolve();
                }
            });

            this.submitService.pollAuditTable().subscribe(res => {
                console.log("res from audit table:\n\t" + res);
                this.auditRows = res;
            });
        }, 10000);  //runs every 10 seconds. will be longer after testing

        console.log('entering wait phase');
    })
}
```

And then how to call it:

```
async someOtherMemberMethod() {
    await this.returned();
    // job is finished here
}
```

or if you don't want to put it in an `async` function:

```
someOtherMemberMethod() {
    this.returned().then(() => {
        // job is finished here
    });
}
```